# match duplicate RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

Imagine there are two tables:

```
TABLE 1:

des    origin   
US     Ireland
US     Germany
Ireland US
```

TABLE 2:

```
des    origin   
Ireland US    
UK      US   
US      Ireland
```

If I do it in SQL, it will be similar to this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE2
            WHERE TABLE1.dest_country_name = TABLE2.origin_country_name)
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE2
            WHERE TABLE1.dest_country_name = TABLE2.origin_country_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Pair rdd of tuple2 (des,origin) with origin and des for both rdds and join the both rdds using join (rdd1.join(rdd2)) .You will get the result.

Comment: Here is the code : val input1  = List("US","US","Ireland")
val input2 = List("Ireland","UK","US")
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(input1)
val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(input2)
val rddPair1= rdd1.map(x => (x,1))
val rddPair2= rdd2.map(x => (x,2))
val rdd3= rddPair1.join(rddPair2)
rdd3.collect